# Grails kill existing process on 8080

Tags: eclipse, grails

Using Eclipse for Grails development.  I often encounter "Address already in use" when doing a run-app from the IDE .  Closing eclipse and restarting kills the existing process, but I'd like to know how to do this with out having to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

In the lower right there should be a panel with the run-app output. There's a red square button at the top of that panel that you can click to stop the server.

Comment: I wish the eclipse plugin could track the running instance of grails like in the servers tab, but the stop button works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate the running app.
You also should push "Remove All Terminated Launches" in the Console Tab of the IDE to get sure that all instances are closed. Use "Display Selected Console" to see all running instances.